# In javascript, use object['property string']. How can I do like that in AngularJS 2?

Tags: angular

I have two objects. A object is {'id': 'abc', 'pwd': 'pwd1'} and B object is Array. B is string of A object property. like this. ['id', 'pwd']

I want use at ng2 component template.

```
*ngFor(#str of B)
   {{A[str]}}
```

But that is not working..
How can i do like javascript? ng2 is using the {{object.property}}.

I don't know how can use like javascript!

++ Edit this vote..

```
template: '<tr *ngFor="#str of B">
    <th>{{str}}</th>
    <td>{{A[str]}}</td>
</tr>'

export class @@{
    A = [{'id': '1', 'pwd': 'pwd1'}];
    b = ['id', 'pwd'];
}
```

I use like that. but that is don't showing values.
How can I do???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let str of B">
      {{A[str]}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  A = {'id': 'abc', 'pwd': 'pwd1'}
  B = ['id', 'pwd'];
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/YqKzjS9UapEtmO2BKF4E?p=preview.

**Edit**

Be careful to use back ticks if you want to define a string on several lines (and not single quotes). In your case for the template attribute of your component.

Comment: Be careful to use back ticks if you want to define a string on several lines (and not single quotes). In your case for the template attribute of your component. I updated my answer with this comment...

Comment: oh my mistake! I was write A = {};. but my source is A = [{}]. your answer is really help for me! my source is very well! Thank you!!  :)